# numerical solution of a transcendental equation

Tags: numerical-methods

I need some help with a program in MATHEMATICA or MAPPLE, that solves the following transcendental equation:
$$\alpha+2x+2\sqrt{\beta+\alpha x+x^{2}}=e^{-t\frac{2}{\alpha}}(\alpha+2\sqrt{\beta})e^{{\frac{2}{\alpha}} (\sqrt{\beta+a(\alpha+a)}-\sqrt{\beta})}$$.
Can someone, please, help me with this issue?
P.S: How can I use this numerical solution, if I need a formula for $x(t)$ to use it further on in calculating some other physical quantities? For instance, I need to calculate pressure=$\frac{1}{x(t)^{6}}$ amd for this I need the expression of $x(t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not really need a computer program to solve this equation. In reality you have an equation of the type
\begin{equation}
\alpha + 2x + 2 \sqrt{\beta + \alpha x + x^2} = f(\alpha, \beta, a, t) =: f.
\end{equation}
You convert into something more manageable by noticing that this equation implies
\begin{equation}
\left( 2 \sqrt{\beta + \alpha x + x^2} \right)^2 = 4 \left( \beta + \alpha x + x^2 \right) = (f - \alpha - 2 x)^2
\end{equation}
which you can easily convert to a second degree equation in $x$. Take care and insert your solution in the original equation.